# Jenkins FindFiles - Multiple files in multiple folders

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

So I have the case that I need to populate findfiles with files from more than one Dir

```
FILES = steps.findFiles(glob: "${FILE}/*.zip")
```

then I need to go to another folder and update it

```
FILES = steps.findFiles(glob: "${AnotherFilePath}/*.zip")
```

End goal is to iterate over the files and for each file do something.
e.g

```
for(file in FILES) {
```

I really want to get away from bash but is it possible to do that Jenkins Groovy way? Can u populate Files Variable?

Comment: just interesting how would you search for files in two folders in shell?

Comment: declare ARTIFACTS=$(find test1 test2  -type f -name "*SNAPSHOT.zip" -or -name "*.zip" | sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [collectMany](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectMany(groovy.lang.Closure)) groovy method that executes closure for every item in initial list and joins result into one array

```
def FILES = [FILE, AnotherFilePath].collectMany{ steps.findFiles(glob: "${it}/*.zip") }
```

Comment: You could search in all subfolders and then filter only required files.

Comment: This is really a smart solution, but I for some reason don't receive output for the zip files : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ysis-create-a-poc-ci-cd-pipeline/platform/permissions-author/target/fsfs-ffsf-author-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip. Maybe the regex doesn't work?

Comment: error is 12:03:37  java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ysis-create-a-poc-ci-cd-pipeline/platform/permissions-author/target/*.zip'. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax

Comment: glob is not a regex. and for `findFiles` it must be relative to workspace - like this: `ysis-create-a-poc-ci-cd-pipeline/platform/permissions-author/target/*.zip`

Comment: This works and is an amazing solution. How did you think of collect many?

Comment: Not sure how to answer this question. Groovy has a lot of methods to avoid iteration explicitly like findAll, collect, collectMany, groupBy... I'm just selecting right tool...